# How can I safely dispose a modal dialog from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to disable my main GUI while running a task and show a "processing" indicator.  This seems easy - just start a thread, show a modal dialog and have the thread dispose the dialog when it's done.

But... it seems like there's a race condition in there.  If my thread completes before I setVisible() my modal dialog, will I be left in a bad state?  Should I call dispose in invokeAndWait or invokeLater?

```java
package scratch;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ModalLoadingImage extends JDialog {
    public ModalLoadingImage(JFrame parent) {
        super(parent, ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        // make nice looking here...
    }

    public void showWhileRunning(Runnable task) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            task.run();
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(() -> dispose());
            } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                ModalLoadingImage d = new ModalLoadingImage(frame);
                d.showWhileRunning(() -> {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `CompletableFuture.runAsync(task) .whenCompleteAsync((v,t) -> dispose(), SwingUtilities::invokeLater);`

Comment: Except for using invokeLater instead of invokeAndWait, that's just a different way of writing the same thing.  My concern is that `dispose` needs to be called after JDialog::setVisible has done enough to be in a state where dispose is ok.

Comment: Assuming that `showWhileRunning` is always invoked in the event dispatch thread (like from your mouse listener), scheduling the `dispose` via `invokeLater` is enough, as that action can only be picked up by the secondary event loop within `setVisible(true)` when the dialog is already open. Yes, I should have addressed that explicitly first. My approach is not only more compact, it also ensures that the dialog will be disposed in every case, i.e. even when `task` threw an exception The alternative to `invokeLater` is to start the new thread in a window listener, when “opened” has been reported